# Another integral double check

Tags: calculus

[image: integral problem]

I have to find the integral for the following problem:

I have completed the following working:
[image: integral problem worked out before peer review]

I am wondering if I am missing any crucial in between steps that will make the solution that much more explanatory.  Thank you for the effort and sorry again for the chicken scratch!!!!

Comment: Towards the end the $5^x$ begins to look like $5x$.

Comment: Oops!  Yeah I am not the best at this so I most definitely appreciate the feedback!  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely correct! As André Nicolas pointed out $5^x$ appeared to be $5x$ near the end in your scratch language. ;)

So the solution is be $\frac{e^{3x^2}}{6} + \frac{5^x}{log 5} + C$, remember that $log$ is in fact a natural logarithm here, so it is the $ln$ button on your calculator. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternate way for

$$\int x e^{3 x^2} \, dx$$

Set
$$\begin{array}{l}
y = {x^2}\\
dy = 2xdx
\end{array}$$

so you cast away the $x$

$$\int x e^{3 x^2} \, dx=\frac{1}{2} \int 2 x e^{3 x^2} \, dx=\frac{1}{2} \int e^{3 y} \, dy=\frac{e^{3 y}}{6}=\frac{e^{3 x^2}}{6}$$

If you are going to use ${ln }$
$$\int 5^x \, dx=\int e^{ln(5) x  } \, dx=\frac{1}{ln(5) }5^x$$

Comment: Yes, I substitude $y = {x^2}$ , $2xdx = dy$ and ${e^{3{x^2}}} = {e^{3y}}$

Comment: +1 for this nice alternate way (an indirectly pointing out that I was initially wrong)